# Why does this SQL PREPARE .. EXECUTE give a syntax error in MySQL 8 but not in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, syntax-error, prepared-statement, mysql-8.0

Yes, yet another question about porting code!

My ISP has 'upgraded' from MariaDB 10.4 to MySQL 8.0 and I have to now tweak a lot of previously working code. The following Stored Procedure has been running without error in MariaDB but in MySQL8 I get a syntax error around `PREPARE` / `EXECUTE`. The actual error is

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 
     'sql_string;
      EXECUTE do_update;
      END LOOP update_table;  -- her' at line 32
```

Can anyone please suggest the correct syntax for MySQL?

(it might be the CONCAT, but that looks right and always worked in MariaDB)

The procedure definition is as follows, the reported syntax error is near the end.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `redact_member_id_in_all_tables`( member_id_to_replace INT, redacted_member_id INT )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE finished INT;
        DECLARE sql_string TEXT;
            DECLARE the_table_name TEXT;
    
        -- declare cursor for a data set containing all the base table names that have a column 'memberID
        -- see https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mariadb/find-tables-with-specific-column-name
        DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
                        SELECT tab.table_name
                        FROM information_schema.tables AS tab
                        INNER JOIN information_schema.columns AS col
                        ON col.table_schema = tab.table_schema
                        AND col.table_name = tab.table_name
                        AND column_name = 'member_id'
                        WHERE tab.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';    
        
        -- declare NOT FOUND handler
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
            SET finished = 0;
            
        -- open the data set containing the table name
        OPEN table_cursor;
        
        update_table: LOOP  -- 'update_table:' is a label identifying this loop
            FETCH table_cursor INTO the_table_name; -- get one table name
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE update_table;
            END IF;
            -- build update statment list
            SET sql_string = CONCAT('UPDATE ', the_table_name, ' SET member_id = ', redacted_member_id, ' WHERE member_id = ', member_id_to_replace)  ;
            
            PREPARE do_update FROM sql_string;
            EXECUTE do_update;
    
        END LOOP update_table;  -- here we use the label to show which loop we are ending
        CLOSE table_cursor; -- release the memory associated with the cursor
    
    END$$
    
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The approach I do, is to substitute parts like filling in the sql_string with an actual string. In this case a look at ["MySQL prepare from variable"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) might propose their syntax. (`@sql_string`)

Comment: Thank you but I still don't see what is incorrect. The link you give shows 

`mysql> SET @table = 't1';
mysql> SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table);
mysql> PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt3;`

which is more or less exactly what I have. I define a string variable containg SQL made by concatenating strings and table column values and then then execute it, just as the link does (except that I don't use parameters, but that shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that mysql only supports PREPARE from a user variable, not a stored procedure variable.  Try:

```
SET @sql_string = sql_string;
PREPARE do_update FROM @sql_string;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html:

> PREPARE stmt_name FROM preparable_stmt
> ...
> preparable_stmt is either a string literal or a user variable

(Though interestingly the [mariadb doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/) says the same thing, and even emphasizes that a DECLAREd variable can't be used; makes me think mariadb was enhanced to allow it but the doc not changed.)

Comment: Thank you. that did it. That's a very subtle difference, no wonder I was scratching my head for so long before giving up and asking here on SO.